# Best indexing strategy for composite primary key with frequently queried columns and occasional additional column

Tags: mysql, query-performance, index, primary-key, clustered-index

I have a large table with the following composite primary key:

```
PRIMARY KEY(col1, col2, col3)
```

col1, col2, col3 are queried all the time.

Some times (maybe 10% of the time) I get queries for col1, col2, col3, col4. Is it worth adjusting the primary key to?:

```
PRIMARY KEY(col1, col2, col3, col4)
```

Or adding a partial index? I'm, not sure what the index would look like or get utilized?

```
INDEX(col4)
```

Or a full composite index?

```
UNIQUE Index(col1, col2, col3, col4)
```

My goal is to optimize query performance, but I'm not sure which approach would be best in this scenario. I'm seeking advice on the pros and cons of each approach and any potential pitfalls to avoid.

Comment: Please provide the schema of the table itself, and a few different example queries that are used against that table.

Comment: Please show us the query that needs the 4 columns.  There may be something else going on.

Answer (score 1):

**No, it generally makes no sense to do so.**

The primary key is itself unique, so a lookup on `col1, col2, col3` already gets a unique row.

In MySQL/InnoDB, a primary key is clustered, so `col4` is already retrieved at the same time as the other three. (In other databases, you would want to ensure it's clustered in your example.) Therefore, another index on `col1, col2, col3, col4` is not going to help, and in fact will be worse as (at least in MySQL) it does not include any other columns being queried.

**The only time such an index is useful** is if you have a wide table, but wish to query only on those four columns (no `SELECT *`). Then it could be beneficial to have a duplicate, but narrower, index.